# How to grep 3 results from the whois command at once?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

Bash 4.3
Ubuntu 16.04

Each `while read` loop takes me a little under a second to accomplish. How can I grep for 3 results at the same time?

```
#!/bin/bash

#-- tmp files
tmp_dir="$(mktemp -d -t 'text.XXXXX' || mktemp -d 2>/dev/null)"
tmp_input1="${tmp_dir}/temp_input1.txt"
tmp_input2="${tmp_dir}/temp_input2.txt"
wDir="/home/work"
list="${wDir}/.ip-list.txt"
finalResults="${wDir}/final-results.txt"

cd "$wDir"
awk '{ print $11 }' "$list" | sort -u > "$tmp_input1"
while read ip; do
   echo "-- IP Address: $ip" >> "$tmp_input2"
   whois "$ip" | grep inetnum >> "$tmp_input2"
   whois "$ip" | grep route >> "$tmp_input2"
   whois "$ip" | grep mnt-by | head -n 2 | sed -n '1!p' >> "$tmp_input2"
   echo "" >> "$tmp_input2"
done<"$tmp_input1"
mv "$tmp_input2" "$finalResults"
cat "$finalResults"
rm -rf "$tmp_dir"
```

Here is my .ip-list.txt file

```
> Tue Oct 16 21:15:59 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 95.217.197.238 62293
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:52 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 95.217.243.116 44076
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:51 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 159.69.253.26 43842
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:47 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 95.217.49.21 13288
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:18 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 95.217.223.72 21969
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:42 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 95.216.232.46 9834
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:54 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 88.198.149.27 23388
> Tue Oct 16 21:15:57 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 95.217.72.11 38498
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:41 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 159.69.250.160 8549
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:27 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 95.217.57.97 52546
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:28 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 95.216.225.43 60635
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:32 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 213.239.244.5 17729
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:05 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 95.217.27.233 24669
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:46 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 94.130.60.83 21203
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:52 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 95.217.191.48 1070
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:22 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 95.217.219.152 15617
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:44 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 95.217.35.111 55808
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:46 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 95.216.224.158 37768
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:13 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 159.69.241.84 24365
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:21 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 95.217.169.49 33710
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:07 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 95.217.186.121 21758
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:00 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 78.47.228.239 21199
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:30 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 95.217.23.171 8670
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:49 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 95.216.244.96 22087
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:20 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 95.217.64.54 13638
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:40 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 95.217.55.104 3377
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:09 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 95.217.242.169 13627
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:54 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 95.217.192.169 6566
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:53 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 95.217.101.221 41547
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:54 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 159.69.227.235 62092
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:45 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 95.217.235.228 63643
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:08 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 80 => 95.216.227.162 51332
> Tue Oct 16 21:16:54 2018 TCP 147.135.23.98 1160 => 95.217.68.128 38480
```

There are hundreds of lines.

How can I make these commands more efficient? Can they be combined?

```
   whois "$ip" | grep inetnum >> "$tmp_input2"
   whois "$ip" | grep route >> "$tmp_input2"
   whois "$ip" | grep mnt-by | head -n 2 | sed -n '1!p' >> "$tmp_input2"
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: you can use `awk` to filter one call to `whois $ip` and produce all the output. Also note that your first `>> "$tmp_input2"` indicates that that file will keep growing. Maybe you want `> "$tmp_input2"` to zero it out you start processing it. Good luck.

Comment: @Cryrus I added to the op

Comment: This could also speed up your script: remove all `>> "$tmp_input2"` and replace `done<"$tmp_input1"` with `done<"$tmp_input1" >> "$tmp_input2"`

Comment: @Cryrus that alone made it about 2 times as fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write output of `whois "$ip"` to a variable and use variable:

```
grep -e 'inetnum' -e 'route' <<< "$out" >> "$tmp_input2"
grep 'mnt-by' <<< "$out" | sed '2!d' >> "$tmp_input2"
```

Comment: thanks. Now the script is twice as fast. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 1):

Not in this way.

The first two greps, you can replace by

whois "$ip" | egrep 'inetnum|route' >> "$tmp_input2"

But because you put the third grep is put through additional filters, you cannot add that one to the egrep.

But `grep` is not the problem; `whois` is the big time consumer. And you run it multiple times.

So, it would be a good idea to limit the number of `whois`-es.

```
hop=$(mktemp)
while read ip; do
    echo "-- IP Address: $ip" >> "$tmp_input2"
    whois "$ip" > $hop 
    grep inetnum $hop >> "$tmp_input2"
    grep route   $hop >> "$tmp_input2"
    grep mnt-by  $hop | head -n 2 | sed -n '1!p' >> "$tmp_input2"
    echo "" >> "$tmp_input2"
done<"$tmp_input1
rm -f $hop
```